# "no more than two authors" in citation call-outs when using harvard citation management package and IOPART document class

Tags: bibtex, citing, harvard-style

IOP Publishing journals require that, if there are more than two authors, only the first name should appear, followed by "et al." (using `\etal` in [`iopart.cls`](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~durduran/topost/iopart.cls)). However, the `dcu` bibliography style (recommended by `iopart`) includes all authors in the text in the first citation if the `harvard` citation management package is loaded. Is there any way to solve this conflict? I would like to use Harvard style with no more than two authors in the text.

To be more specific, I am creating an `iopart` document and using the Harvard alphabetical style for references. I am reading from a bib file, and use `\citeasnoun{ref}` in the text. I also use [`dcu.bst`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/dcu.bst) to include article titles in the references.

Comment: Do you want to change the `dcu.bst` style to get this abbreviation? (Adding a MWE to your question will be a good idea to help the other readers to understand what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For publications with 3 or more authors and if the `harvard` citation management package is loaded, the `dcu` bibliography style is designed to include the names of all authors of a given publication the first time the publication is cited; from the second citation onward, the abbreviated form `firstauthor et al` is used for citation call-outs.

The user guide of the `harvard` package mentions that the default setting can be overridden, i.e., that one can generate abbreviated citation call-outs beginning with the very first time a piece is cited, by issuing the instruction

```
\citationmode{abbr}
```

after loading the `harvard` package in the preamble.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{abc, author="Author and Buthor and Cuthor", title="Title", year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{iopart}
\usepackage{harvard}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\citationmode{abbr}  % <-- new

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citeasnoun{abc} argue that \dots
\section*{References}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

A different solution may be achieved by not loading the `harvard` package at all and, instead, by loading the `natbib` package, all while still using the `dcu` bibliography style. With this solution, it's actually best to load the `har2nat` package, which loads the `natbib` package automatically while preserving some of the special capabilities of the `harvard` package.

A full MWE (no screenshot provided, as it would be essentially the same as the one shown above):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{abc, author="Author and Buthor and Cuthor", title="Title", year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{iopart}
\usepackage{har2nat}  % loads 'natbib' automatically
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\providecommand\newblock{} % suppress some meaningless warnings

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{abc} argue that \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `biblatex` package (http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) has a variable `maxnames` for this

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber, maxnames=2]{biblatex}
```