# Why does Harvard style in overleaf print more than two authors?

Tags: overleaf, harvard-style, bibliographystyle

I would like to use Harvard style in overleaf, therefore I use

```
\usepackage[sorting=nyt,style=apa,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\begin{document}
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and then use  `\autocite{}`, but it prints four authors names. I tried to use \natbib, but it was not comaptible with overleaf. Then I tried  `authoryear-ibid` style again the problem was the same. Is there any trick that I could solve this problem? `agsm` style does not work on overleaf as well.

PS1. I went through this page as well [enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles), but I could not find a solution. I also saw [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434968/no-more-than-two-authors-in-citation-call-outs-when-using-harvard-citation-man), but Overleaf gets errors about Harvard style.

PS2. For some, it shows just one, and the et. al for some it prints 3 or 4 author names.

Comment: overleaf is not related to this question (it is using standard texlive packages so you would see the same behaviour in any tex system) You can use natbib with overleaf if you wish, why do you say it is not compatible?  Please fix your example so that people can run it and see the problem.

Comment: APA style rules require inclusion of more author names to make author lists unique (https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/same-year-first-author), so that is what `style=apa,` does. If you don't want real APA style it is better not to use `style=apa,`. ...

Comment: ... A style like `style=authoryear-ibid,` might be more appropriate if you do not want APA style. By default the styles of the `biblatex` standard styles of the `authoryear` family also add more names (and name initials) to make citation labels unique, but this can be turned off: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864.